# Check if all files exist in a directory batch scripting

Tags: file, batch-file, directory

I am trying to write a batch script(I am only a Beginner) that will allow me to go into a directory and check if 5 files exist. These files are: 
eim_account.dat eim_contact.dat eim_employee.dat eim_accnt_dtl.dat eim_fn_asset.dat
So Far i have this written and need help continuing from here:

```
@echo off 
SET dir1=C:\TestScript\
SET LogFile=C:\TestScript\logfile.log 
SET res=false

FOR /F %%a IN ('dir /b %dir1%eim_*.dat' /O:D /T:C) do (

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
@echo OFF
for %%a in (eim_account.dat eim_contact.dat eim_employee.dat eim_accnt_dtl.dat eim_fn_asset.dat) do (
  if NOT exist C:\TestScript\%%a echo %%a doesnt exist
)
pause
```

I assumed `C:\TestScript\` is where your *.dat files are.